# Non-interactive method for dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Tags: ubuntu, automation, timezone

When I first setup an Ubuntu server, I make sure I `aptitude install tzdata`, then `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` so that I set my timezone properly.

I am trying to automate my server setup with a script, and noticed this piece sort of throws a wrench into it being automatic, as it requires an interactive session with user intervention.

Is there a way to use dpkg-reconfigure without it being interactive?

Comment: sudo EDITOR='sed -Ei "
    s|tzdata/Areas=.+|tzdata/Areas=\"Asia\"|;
    s|tzdata/Zones/Asia=.+|tzdata/Zones/Asia=\"Shanghai\"|
    "' dpkg-reconfigure -f editor tzdata


Related answer: [How do you set a locale non-interactively on Debian/Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/a/1114285)

Answer (score 89):

The answer by swill is not how it is done properly. If you want unattended/scripted dpkg configuration of packages, then you want to use the debconf preseeding mechanism.

In your case this means that you have to do the following:

- set the following environment variables to avoid that debconf tries to ask the user any questions:

  ```
  export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true
  ```
- then preseed debconf with the following preseed.txt file (or whatever other settings you desire):

  ```
  tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe
  tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Berlin
  ```
- you set the above preseed file by running:

  ```
  debconf-set-selections /your/preseed.txt
  ```
- you can now either install tzdata (if it is not installed yet) via `apt` or run `dpkg-reconfigure`. In the end, tzdata will be set up according to what you specified in your debconf preseed file.

Remember that you can automate lots more using debconf preseeding. For example in my preseeds I always set:

```
locales locales/locales_to_be_generated multiselect     en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
locales locales/default_environment_locale      select  en_US.UTF-8
```

You can always inspect the debconf settings of your current system by running `debconf-get-selections`. The output should give you some idea of how much of the system configuration you are able to automate using debconf preseeding.

Comment: At the end I had to call `dpkg-reconfigure` with `-f noninteractive` anyway… (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS here). Otherwise, your instructions worked great!

Comment: Works great pre install, but I dont think this actually works for case where the pkg is already installed. AFAIK you have to remove the pkg first.

Comment: @S.Pinkus you're right; it's necessary to remove `/etc/{localtime,timezone}` when tzdata is already installed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39275359/161114 .

Comment: Doing this remotely through ssh: `$ ssh node 'export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true;echo -e "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe\ntzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Amsterdam" > /tmp/tz ; sudo debconf-set-selections /tmp/tz; sudo rm /etc/localtime /etc/timezone; sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f non-interactive tzdata' `

Comment: @hbogert your usage of `/tmp/tz` is a security problem. By the time you read from `/tmp/tz` others could've written a different value to it or the file already existed (which you didn't check) and you are overwriting it. Use `mktemp` to avoid all these problems. Also, you are forgetting to remove your temporary file at the end. Lastly, your using of `-e` as argument to `echo` is not portable and you should use `printf` instead for the newlines.

Comment: Why is this preferable to swill's (simpler) answer? What is more "proper" about using a preseed file as opposed to changing `/etc/timezone`?

Comment: In a Dockerfile for Ubuntu 20.04 using "apt install tzdata", this is the only solution mentioned here that worked for me; in particular, setting the two environment variables was critical or apt install would still prompt interactively.

Answer (score 43):

Doing this in a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

## for apt to be noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

## preesed tzdata, update package index, upgrade packages and install needed software
RUN truncate -s0 /tmp/preseed.cfg; \
    echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" >> /tmp/preseed.cfg; \
    echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Berlin" >> /tmp/preseed.cfg; \
    debconf-set-selections /tmp/preseed.cfg && \
    rm -f /etc/timezone /etc/localtime && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y tzdata

## cleanup of files from setup
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

In my experiments I determined the removal of the files in `/etc` necesssary.

Comment: Note: It is dangerous to `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND...` because using `ENV` will make the variable persist into the environment when the container starts running too (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env for a warning about this). [Looking around](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4032#issuecomment-192327844) you can see that `ARG` should be preferred in this situation (e.g. `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND...`) because the variable's value is only in effect while the container is being built.

Comment: While I'm with you for *passwords*, *api keys* and stuff like that, it still depends in this specific situation, if you *want to embed* these *configuration values* into the container image or not. Confusion for users may be an issue...

Comment: This solutions works on focal 20.04 too. I used to use the settings of `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=...` and `TZ=...` for bionic 18.04 and trusty 16.04, but it would fail on focal. Followed [another topic on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/949991/how-to-install-tzdata-on-a-ubuntu-docker-image/1044731#1044731).

Answer (score 36):

There is a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806, not fixed at the time of writing this answer) in 16.04 which causes the contents of `/etc/timezone` to be overwritten with the old value when running `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata`. The fix is as follows (from the above bug report):

```
$ sudo ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
Current default time zone: 'America/New_York'
Local time is now:      Mon Feb 20 07:30:33 EST 2017.
Universal Time is now:  Mon Feb 20 12:30:33 UTC 2017.
$ cat /etc/timezone
America/New_York
```

No need to manually change the contents of `/etc/timezone`. This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: The easiest, the cleanest, the best.
(Working in Ubuntu 16.04.4)

Comment: This isn't a bug. Rather, the intended behavior (`ln -fs...`) is described in [comment #9 on that ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806/comments/9). Also, this question is now off-topic for SO. Please don't encourage OT questions by answering them :)

Answer (score 20):

Here's my `Dockerfile` for the latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distro, adapted from the answer by @NilsBallmann. I also removed temp file creation and compacted the package installation into a single layer:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; \
    export DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true; \
    echo 'tzdata tzdata/Areas select Etc' | debconf-set-selections; \
    echo 'tzdata tzdata/Zones/Etc select UTC' | debconf-set-selections; \
    apt-get update -qqy \
 && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
        tzdata \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Perfect!. Ubuntu 20.04 docker works well!

Comment: However, using apt command after rm-rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
RUN apt update <--- must be added.

Comment: @coverboy what is the point of running `apt update` after explicitly and intentionally deleting the caches produced by apt?

Comment: To install another package :-)

Comment: The simplest option is simply to add the extra package to `apt-get install` list above, so that it's installed alongside `tzdata`. But if for whatever reason you have to use a separate RUN instruction, then you'll need to run `apt-get update` again.

EDIT: The reason being that we want to clean up at the end of each RUN instruction, otherwise we're going to end up with an unnecessarily bloated layer in the resulting docker image.

Answer (score 13):

Advancing [josch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20693661/161114)'s answer; set the debconf db values and **remove `/etc/{localtime,timezone}`** before running `dpkg-reconfigure`:-

```
$ echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" > some/file.txt
$ echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Berlin" >> some/file.txt
$ sudo debconf-set-selections some/file.txt
$ sudo rm /etc/timezone
$ sudo rm /etc/localtime
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Berlin'
Local time is now:      Thu Sep  1 17:13:16 CEST 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Sep  1 15:13:16 UTC 2016.
```

This method is known to work on:-

- Ubunty Trusty (14.04.5 LTS)

Comment: You don't need the temporary file. Just `printf 'tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe\ntzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Berlin\n' | sudo dpkg-set-selections`

Comment: And I don't think you need to explicitly remove the files in `/etc` which `dpkg-reconfigure` will be rewriting anyway.

Comment: Thank you man, you saved me! It also works on Docker Container: debian:stretch or ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 18.04 with systemd, I'm using:

```
  $ sudo timedatectl set-timezone 'Europe/Madrid'
  $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: Where does this go?

Comment: It looks like that there is no need in second command.

Comment: note: `timedatectl` comes from `systemd` pkg, which not always availble

Comment: The second command is needed because `timedatectl` does not update the `/etc/timezone` Debian-specific file. Source: https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges