# reconfigure timezone inside docker not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, timezone

First, I configure timezone in my Dockerfile as below, but it fails(as I go inside docker container and execute 'date', only to get a Etc/UTC time).

```
   FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:3.0.1-aluminum
   USER root
   RUN echo "Asia/Shanghai" > /etc/timezone
   RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Then, I try again as below, it seems 'dpkg-reconfigure' reset the /etc/timezone. So what's wrong on earth?

[image]

**Supplement**:
After I follow the method as BMitch suggested, it does make a step forward, but another confusing problem occurs: date command inside docker container prints a wrong time.
[image]

Comment: see here (solution with debconf):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671308/non-interactive-method-for-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium bases their images on Ubuntu, and Ubuntu changed the behavior of a non-interactive tzdata reconfigure from the standard Debian method. Use the following instead:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:3.0.1-aluminum
USER root
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime \
 && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806) for more details.

Comment: yeah, it helps to make a step forward. 
And then another question following: I execute 'date' inside the running docker container, it still show a wrong time.
 ```root@3676e853f0c0:/# dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Asia/Shanghai'
Local time is now:      Fri Dec  2 11:33:11 CST 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Dec  2 03:33:11 UTC 2016. 
root@3676e853f0c0:/# date
Thu Dec  1 19:33:15 PST 2016```

Comment: Make sure you don't have TZ defined in your environment (`unset TZ`). After the reconfigure you should also see /etc/timezone contains "Asia/Shanghai".

Comment: Perfect! Thank u so much.